# Java Date convert dd-MMM-yyyy to dd MMMMMMMMMM yyyyy?

Tags: java, android, date

The following method returns date example:

**11 Mar 2015**

instead of:

**11 March 2015**

Code:

```
public static String convertDat(String s) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat converted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM yyyy ");
    SimpleDateFormat incoming = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date currentDate = (Date) incoming.parse(s);
    return converted.format(currentDate);
}
```

Comment: `MMM` gives you exactly what you see, `MMMM` gives you the full month text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `DateFormat` should be like

```
SimpleDateFormat converted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

From the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs

> M month in year 
>   M:1 MM:01 MMM:Jan **MMMM:January** MMMMM:J

Comment: What does `MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM` do?